# Unity Spatializer from Oculus Integration package for Unity throwing errors when it hasn't been touched

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

The build runs fine within the editor no issues at all. But when trying to build for the Android/PC, Mac & Linux Standalone/Universal Windows Platform unity throws about 30 errors at me (image below) all belonging to a range of scripts within the Unity Audio Spatializer. I have not touched these scripts I don't even know what they are. Does anyone have a fix?

[Image Of All Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QbyF.png)

```
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPAudioPluginUpdater.cs(24,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Callbacks' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationSerializationManager.cs(22,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Build' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationSerializationManager.cs(24,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SceneManagement' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationMaterialEditor.cs(29,55): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Editor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPAudioPluginUpdater.cs(32,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InitializeOnLoadAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPAudioPluginUpdater.cs(32,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InitializeOnLoad' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationMaterialEditor.cs(28,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CustomEditorAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationMaterialEditor.cs(28,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CustomEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationMaterialEditor.cs(515,24): error CS0115: 'ONSPPropagationMaterialEditor.OnInspectorGUI()': no suitable method found to override
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPAudioPluginUpdater.cs(106,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MenuItemAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPAudioPluginUpdater.cs(106,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MenuItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPAudioSourceEditor.cs(29,50): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Editor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPAudioSourceEditor.cs(27,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CustomEditorAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPAudioSourceEditor.cs(27,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CustomEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPAudioSourceEditor.cs(41,23): error CS0115: 'OculusSpatializerUserParamsEditor.OnInspectorGUI()': no suitable method found to override
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationSerializationManager.cs(42,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BuildTarget' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationGeometryEditor.cs(28,46): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Editor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationGeometryEditor.cs(27,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CustomEditorAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationGeometryEditor.cs(27,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CustomEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationGeometryEditor.cs(30,23): error CS0115: 'ONSPPropagationGeometryEditor.OnInspectorGUI()': no suitable method found to override
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationSerializationManager.cs(47,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MenuItemAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationSerializationManager.cs(47,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MenuItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPReflectionCustomGUI.cs(25,53): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAudioEffectPluginGUI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationSerializationManager.cs(53,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MenuItemAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPPropagationSerializationManager.cs(53,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MenuItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPReflectionCustomGUI.cs(42,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAudioEffectPlugin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPReflectionCustomGUI.cs(27,28): error CS0115: 'OculusSpatializerReflectionCustomGUI.Name': no suitable method found to override
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPReflectionCustomGUI.cs(32,28): error CS0115: 'OculusSpatializerReflectionCustomGUI.Description': no suitable method found to override
Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor\ONSPReflectionCustomGUI.cs(37,28): error CS0115: 'OculusSpatializerReflectionCustomGUI.Vendor': no suitable method found to override
```

I've tried setting the spatializer plugin within Project Settings > Audio to OculuSpatializer
I've tried the 'Build audio geometry for current scene' and 'Rebuild audio geometry for all scenes'

Comment: Please don't post images. The question should contain all relevant information within the question itself as text, including a [mre].

Comment: @ChrisMM added all errors as text

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all the files within the Assets\Imported\Oculus\VR\Spatializer\editor folder worked